# How destructive would a antimatter bomb be?

Tags: science-fiction, warfare, weapons, space, aliens

I already know that antimatter is a destructive thing. But *how* destructive is it? I want in my far future human reality there be a mass produced bomb using antimatter that makes sure aliens know to not mess with us, let's say about 85 kilos of antimatter is used. Would destroy planets and moons or leave planets wastelands?

Comment: How are you using the antimatter within the bomb? The effects are going to be very different if you use a matter-antimatter reaction as an airburst nuke, or an impact detonated nuke, or you find a way to keep the antimatter contained and deliver it to the surface of a planet as a blob that reacts with the surface directly.

Comment: *"I already know that antimatter is a destructive thing. But how destructive is it?"* the energy released will be total mass annihilated, times light speed squared. E=mc2 !

Comment: The simple answer is this: Really d*** destructive.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments made on my more general answer the weapons in question must be mixed fuel containment models with two streams of particles wrapped around each other, one of matter, the other antimatter. Because that's how you maximise the efficiency of an antimatter reaction, finely mix the particles and then allow them to react. This means that such weapons are 3.655GT TNT nuclear bombs, or the equivalent of thirty six and a half [Tsar Bombas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba) (with uranium fusion tamper) strapped together. The output of these weapons is almost pure gamma radiation so it's not going to directly create any great amount of heat nor, if detonated on or above the surface, cratering/ground shock. Atmospheric blast and fireball effects are going to be different as well, they're not directly due to the heat of detonation but the response of the air to ionising gamma rays. You could use that ionising radiation to kill everything on half a small planet and damage the atmosphere, you would need two bombs to kill everything *all at once* but one would probably kill everything eventually. A shaped charge/deeply buried blast of that magnitude could blow a small astral body apart but you'd need a gamma reflector shell to do it with antimatter, otherwise most of the gamma penetrates too far before interacting with the matter immediately around the bomb.

Answer (score 0):

Without any of the finesse details about how you're delivering the antimatter explosion, which would make individual scenarios, like "what happens to the moon if I hit it with one of these?", examinable, you're talking about a reaction with a total yield of 3.655GT TNT (~1.5x10<sup>19</sup>J). Apparently that's [slightly more than the entire world's nuclear arsenal as of 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)#1018_to_1023_J). You can almost certainly sterilise the ground surface of at least half a planet with a weapon like that, and boil surface waters. You'd possibly even melt exposed soil and crust over a reasonable percentage of one hemisphere. Antimatter reactions tend to be very clean so the initial output is almost pure [Gamma Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray), secondary radiogenic cascade may cause long term contamination.

Comment: The antimatter would be contained using magnetic fields. The container of antimatter would be completely empty of any thing else to stop an early explosion. When needed you can set to explode at a certain height if needed, or in most cases you just let it drop. Either at contact or height met the magnetic fields completely shutoff and the antimatter can go wild in the container, and you know what happens next. Hopes this help.

Comment: @AstronautAxolotl Is the container designed for full mass conversion on detonation or does it hold an excess of antimatter that will react with the environment directly?

Comment: All antimatter explodes when detonation requirements are met for a maximum force explosion